# C#: Refactoring a Reynolds number calculator

Tags: c#, refactoring

I'm trying to learn some C# over the weekend and am following the 15 exercises found here: http://www.jobsnake.com/seek/articles/index.cgi?openarticle&8533

Yesterday I asked a similar question for the Fibonacci sequence and received some great responses which introduced me to elements of C# which I'd not encountered before: 
[Refactoring Fibonacci Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406446/refactoring-fibonacci-algorithm)

Today I would like to see how a C# Jedi would refactor the following code:

```
static string Reynolds(int d, int v, int rho, int mu)
{
    int number = (d*v*rho) / mu;
    if (number < 2100) return "Laminar Flow";
    else if (number < 2100 && number < 4000) return "Transient Flow";
    else return "Turbulent Flow";
}
```

So more simple than yesterday, but is there any nice way to deal with the multiple conditionals?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: You should change the parameters to doubles since most physical values are real numbers. Your else if should test for number >= 2100 since if "number < 2100" is false then "number >= 2100" is true. In other words, you need to test for number being between 2100 and 4000, or 2100 <= number < 4000.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is an error in your code but I made an assumption. Your second "if" would never evaluate tree as number < 2000 already makes the first branch true.

I would create an ENUM:

```
enum FlowType
{
    Laminar
    , Transient
    , Turbulent
};


static FlowType Reynolds(int d, int v, int rho, int mu)
{
    int n = (d*v*rho) / mu;

    if(n < 2000)
    {
        return FlowType.Laminar;
    }
    else if(n < 4000)
    {
        return FlowType.Transient;
    }
    else
    {
        return FlowType.Turbulent;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "n >= 2000" is redundant, you can omit it without changing the semantics of the code.

Comment: As coded, you need to change the return type. You coded the method as if you are returning values of type FlowType, but the method signature states that you are returning strings.

Also, the test n >= 2000 is not necessary.

Comment: I was in between edits. Also, as for the unncessary >= 2000 check, the problem was there was an error in the original and had forgot to remove that when correcting the original.

Answer (score 3):

Using the C# ternary operator,

```
   static string Reynolds(int d, int v, int rho, int mu)
    {        
       int number = (d*v*rho) / mu; 
       return number <  2100? "Laminar Flow":
              number >= 4000? "Turbulent Flow":
                              "Transient Flow";
    }
```

or, (to give my sarcastic side a bit of free rein), if you find this not ***readable***, you could add comments, to make it ***more*** readable,

```
static string Reynolds(int d, int v, int rho, int mu)
{        
   int number = (d*v*rho) / mu; 
   return /*IF*/ number <  2100? /*Then*/ "Laminar Flow":
          /*IF*/ number >= 4000? /*Then*/ "Turbulent Flow":
                                 /*Else*/ "Transient Flow";
}
```

Does anyone really think that helps?

Comment: This is compact but not very readable. Although, he didn't ask for that. :)

Comment: Ick ick ick. Chained ternaries == the devil.

Comment: This is just the kind of functional programming example one sees in OCaml or Haskell. Why should it not be written in C#?

Comment: I don't think the comments make it more readable. It's not a bad solution. It's a style preference. I prefer to have the nested ifs, sometimes I may decide I want to add extra code. I use ternaries of course, I rarely use nested ternaries.