# C# fibonacci function returning errors

Tags: c#, console-application, fibonacci

I am practising a C# console application, and I am trying to get the function to verify if the number appears in a fibonacci series or not but I'm getting errors.

What I did was:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(isFibonacci(20));
    }
    static int isFibonacci(int n)
    {
        int[] fib = new int[100];
        fib[0] = 1;
        fib[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

            if (n == fib[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }



        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean #DEFINE errors ?

Comment: Just curious, but why are you returning an int rather than a bool?

Comment: @Joel I'm guessing he was introduced to C before C#, where `bool` doesn't exist and integer values `1` and `0` are commonly used for `true` and `false`, respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And here is a solution that beats all of yours!

Because, why **iteration** when you have smart **mathematicians** doing **closed-form solutions** for you? :)

```
static bool IsFibonacci(int number)
{
    //Uses a closed form solution for the fibonacci number calculation.
    //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

    double fi = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2.0; //Golden ratio
    int n = (int) Math.Floor(Math.Log(number * Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5, fi)); //Find's the index (n) of the given number in the fibonacci sequence

    int actualFibonacciNumber = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Pow(fi, n) / Math.Sqrt(5) + 0.5); //Finds the actual number corresponding to given index (n)

    return actualFibonacciNumber == number;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Here's a fun solution using an infinite iterator block:

```
IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci()
{
   int n1 = 0;
   int n2 = 1;

   yield return 1;
   while (true)
   {
      int n = n1 + n2;
      n1 = n2;
      n2 = n;
      yield return n;
   }
}

bool isFibonacci(int n)
{
    foreach (int f in Fibonacci())
    {
       if (f > n) return false;
       if (f == n) return true;
    }
}
```

I actually really like this kind of Fibonacci implementation vs the tradition recursive solution, because it keeps the work used to complete a term available to complete the next. The traditional recursive solution duplicates some work, because it needs two recursive calls each term.

Answer (score 10):

The problem lies in <= the following statement:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
```

more to the point the =. There is no fib[100] (C# zero counts) so when you check  on i=100 you get an exception.

the proper statement should be

```
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
```

or even better

```
for (int i = 2; i < fib.Length; i++)
```

Comment: +1 I'm amazed that highest answer and accepted answer don't point out the reason of error. **This is the actual problem with his code.** He's getting **Index out of range exception** because of accessing `fib[100]` while the last item is `fib[99]`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, for starters your array is only 10 long and you're filling it with ~100 items (out-of-range-exception) - but there are better ways to do this...

for example, using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406446/refactoring-fibonacci-algorithm/406448#406448):

```
long val = ...
bool isFib = Fibonacci().TakeWhile(x => x <= val).Last() == val;
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is check for an early exit.  Since you're trying to determine if a given number is in the Fibonacci sequence, you can do bounds checking to exit early.

Example:

```
static bool isFibonacci(int n)
{
    int[] fib = new int[100];
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= fib.Length; i++)
    {
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

        if (n == fib[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (n < fib[i])
        {
            return false;  //your number has been surpassed in the fib seq
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Probably should throw an exception if the end of the array is met: function is not able to give an answer in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] fib = new int[10];
for (int i = 2; i <= *100*; i++)
```

You're going out of the bounds of your array because your loop conditional is too large. A more traditional approach would be to bound the loop by the size of the array:

```
for (int i = 2; i < fib.Length; i++)
```

And make your array bigger, but as Marc said, there are better ways to do this, and I would advise you spend some time reading the wikipedia article on [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int FibNo(int n) {
    int result = 0; int No = 0; int N1 = 1;

    if (n< 0)
    { throw new ArguementException("number must be a positive value"); }

    if (n <= 1) 
    { result = n; return result; }

    for(int x=1; x < n; x++) 
    { result = No + N1; No = N1; N1=result; }

    return result;

}
```