# What is the purpose of Yield and how does it work?

Tags: c#, yield-return

While perusing Twitter I spotted a tweet by a Game Developer I follow that just said;

> <sup>[@ChevyRay](https://twitter.com/ChevyRay) [2:44 AM - 5 Jul 2016](https://twitter.com/ChevyRay/status/750143351572140032)</sup>
>   *i give you: the stupidest 8 lines of code i’ve ever written that is actually used by my game’s code*
>
> ```cs
> static IEnumerable<int> RightAndleft
> {
>     get
>     {
>         yield return 1;
>         yield return -1;
>     }
> }
> ```

Immediately I looked at it and thought to myself what does this do? I'm sure the post was meant as an in-joke but I just didn't get it. So with that I went and researched [`yield`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/yield) but that didn't really answer my question.

I wondered if anyone here could shed some light on firstly what it's doing and also why.

Comment: It returns 2 ints, 1 and -1 for left and right ..

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply @BugFinder but that is what I'm trying to understand, how can a property return two values, is that what `yield` allows you to do? I guess I just don't get the syntax?

Comment: @Lankymart: It returns an `IEnumerable<int>` that, when enumerated, will yield `1` and `-1` in that order, and nothing else.

Comment: @Joey That is interesting, so it's a way to return an enumerable type without having to first add the values? Apologies if I sound thick, just trying to make sure I understand.

Comment: @Lankymart: It avoids creating an array, or a list in this case. Instead this method is turned into a class with state-keeping fields and logic by the compiler so that the enumerator knows in which line it has been the last time and what to do to return the next value. I'm not terribly sure whether this isn't more expensive, though. A better way might be to just return a static array with both values.

Comment: @Joey According to the twitter conversation it's less expensive which is why they use it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There's a lot of compiler magic going on here. See what the compiler turns this into: it creates an inner class (a state-machine) and `RightAndLeft` returns an instance of this class. http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AMpAI457TxJrrEDCA9gDZuoDGyYLEIYgHFUEVACcwXHNgAOwAEZspMLmwCGIEDCbYA3thhGYKdby4wAkgFEIwdBPVLUAHkjIAfDABKYKAAtkAEEIABNOADNkGANjOJgoVGjY+KMASAQwVDZQmHEk4HEIGABGHFT0zOzc/ORC4oBaMsNjNIBfFqMOtqA==

Comment: @Dennis_E Ah, so it's a form of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Comment: @Lankymart It's **a lot** of syntactic sugar. This guy always explains things very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or9g8LOhXhg&list=PL9B5E4C37F7B234A8&index=3

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks for the video links, very informative!

Comment: @Lankymart yeild is a simpler (or at least simiilar but) less painful version of List<blah> x, do stuff adding to x as required or not, return x..

Comment: @BugFinder I think what I get from it is, it allows you to avoid temp Lists or handle lazy loading list *(infinite lists)* efficiently. Just populating a List infinitely will eventually cause it to error, where as using `yield` will not.

Comment: yep. Yield is in a way quite a brain changer for those of us who coded in the days before it, however.. it is a lovely way of handling it

Comment: @BugFinder This is so awesome [C# fibonacci function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076045/692942) using `yield`.

Comment: @Lankymart yep. Its a real good programming tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler turns this code into an enumerator. You can use this enumerator to iterate over the sequence `{1, -1}`:

```
foreach(var i in ClassName.RightAndLeft)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

results in

```
1
-1
```

Note that this property does *not* have two return statements and return type `int`. It returns an `IEnumerable<int>`, a sequence containing `1` and `-1`.

See [yield keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) for more information.

One important part to note is that the second line `yield return -1;` is executed *after* the first value has been printed out by `Console.WriteLine` in this example.

---

Since the poster is a game developer, he probably uses these two values as direction indicators and this enumeration to, well, enumerate all possible directions or something like that.

Comment: How can a property have two return statements, is that what `yield` allows you to do?

Comment: @Lankymart `yield` tells the compiler to build an enumerator out of this code. The return type of the property is _not_ `int`, it's `IEnumerable<int>`. I added a link to an explanation of `yield`  works.

Comment: Thanks @RenéVogt I'm a lot clearer on what it is doing now.

Comment: Weird, someone decided to downvote both the question and your answer on Jun 12th at 17:00. Noticed the question had been flagged for closure but it was invalidated. Honestly i've seen far worse questions on [so] over the years. Didn't downvote the other answer though...you get on the wrong side of someone? ;)

Answer (score 1):

It returns `IEnumerable<int>` object that contains `1` and `-1`.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: It doesn't really _contain_ them. It can _produce_ them when asked, though.