# Generating Fibonacci series in F#

Tags: f#, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I'm just starting to learn F# using VS2010 and below is my first attempt at generating the Fibonacci series.  What I'm trying to do is to build a list of all numbers less than 400.

```
let fabList = 
    let l =  [1;2;]
    let mutable a = 1
    let mutable b = 2
    while l.Tail < 400 do
        let c = a + b
        l.Add(c)
        let a = b
        let b = c
```

My first problem is that on the last statement, I'm getting an error message "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in expression" on the last line.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

While this seems to be an obvious way to build the list in a fairly efficient way (from a c++/C# programmer), from what little I know of f#, this doesn't seem to feel to be the right way to do the program.  Am I correct in this feeling?

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong. You're using a functional programming language like a procedural one. Try doing it without using `while` or any similar loop constructs at first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, you're using `let` as if it was a statement to mutate a variable, but that's not the case. In F#, `let` is used to declare a new value (which may hide any previous values of the same name). If you want to write code using mutation, then you need to use something like:

```
let c = a + b  // declare new local value
l.Add(c)  
a <- b   // mutate value marked as 'mutable'
b <- c   // .. mutate the second value
```

The second issue with your code is that you're trying to mutate F# list by adding elements to it - F# lists are immutable, so once you create them, you cannot modify them (in particular, there is no `Add` member!). If you wanted to write this using mutation, you could write:

```
let fabList = 
  // Create a mutable list, so that we can add elements 
  // (this corresponds to standard .NET 'List<T>' type)
  let l = new ResizeArray<_>([1;2])
  let mutable a = 1
  let mutable b = 2
  while l.[l.Count - 1] < 400 do
    let c = a + b
    l.Add(c) // Add element to the mutable list
    a <- b
    b <- c
  l |> List.ofSeq // Convert any collection type to standard F# list
```

But, as others already noted, writing the code in this way isn't the idiomatic F# solution. In F#, you would use immutable lists and recursion instead of loops (such as `while`). For example like this:

```
// Recursive function that implements the looping
// (it takes previous two elements, a and b)
let rec fibsRec a b =
  if a + b < 400 then
    // The current element
    let current = a + b
    // Calculate all remaining elements recursively 
    // using 'b' as 'a' and 'current' as 'b' (in the next iteration)
    let rest = fibsRec b current  
    // Return the remaining elements with 'current' appended to the 
    // front of the resulting list (this constructs new list, 
    // so there is no mutation here!)
    current :: rest
  else 
    [] // generated all elements - return empty list once we're done

// generate list with 1, 2 and all other larger fibonaccis
let fibs = 1::2::(fibsRec 1 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Immutablity as a normal programming mode is something that I'm still trying to get use to and your explanation clarified concepts for me.  Not to mention functional programming.

Comment: @photo_tom: That's how all of us who have imperative background feel for the first time :-). Immutability is one of the essential concepts and the rest of functional ideas follow from that.

Comment: Very nice answer. One point worthwhile mentioning would be the fact that as a general approach when creating recursive functions the Call to the function it self should always be the last operation in that particular branch so that a tail Call optimization Can be performed. In this particular case with 400 as the limit a stackoverflow is of cause usually not an issue

Answer (score 52):

Other posts tell you how to write the while loop using recursive functions. This is another way by using the [Seq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx) library in F#:

```
// generate an infinite Fibonacci sequence
let fibSeq = Seq.unfold (fun (a,b) -> Some( a+b, (b, a+b) ) ) (0,1)
// take the first few numbers in the sequence and convert the sequence to a list
let fibList = fibSeq |> Seq.takeWhile (fun x -> x<=400 ) |> Seq.toList
```

for explanation, please ref [solution 2](http://fsharp-euler.wikispaces.com/euler+002) in [F# for Project Euler Problems](http://fsharp-euler.wikispaces.com), where the first 50 Euler problems are solved. I think you will be interested in these solutions.

Comment: Thanks for link - for F# for Project Euler Problems.  I am working on some of those problems to help learn F#.

Comment: I think the first line should actually be:

let fibSeq = Seq.unfold (fun (a,b) -> Some( a+b, (a+b, a) ) ) (0,1)

Comment: Is there any way of doing this functionally without repeating the a+b?

Comment: The F# for Project Euler Problems website has expired, here's an archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20120702222856/http://fsharp-euler.wikispaces.com/

Answer (score 14):

```
let rec fibSeq p0 p1 = seq {
    yield p0
    yield! fibSeq p1 (p0+p1)
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because bare code, with no explanation, is not likely to help an OP who describes himself as "just starting to learn F#".

Comment: np. I agree with the reason.

Comment: Nice, infinite sequence to be evaluated lazily. Just don't try to convert the infinite seq to an array or List, unless you have a lot of RAM ;).

Comment: It is worth noting to pipe fibSeq to Seq.Cache for better performance

Answer (score 7):

Here's an infinite tail-recursive solution using sequence expressions.  It's quite efficient, producing the 100,000th term in just a few seconds.  The "yield" operator is just like C#'s "yield return", and the "yield!" operator may be read as "yield all", where in C# you would have to do "foreach item ... yield return item".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296664/code-chess-fibonacci-sequence/2892670#2892670

```
let fibseq =    
    let rec fibseq n1 n2 = 
        seq { let n0 = n1 + n2 
              yield n0
              yield! fibseq n0 n1 }
    seq { yield 1I ; yield 1I ; yield! (fibseq 1I 1I) }

let fibTake n = fibseq |> Seq.take n //the first n Fibonacci numbers
let fib n = fibseq |> Seq.nth (n-1) //the nth Fibonacci number
```

This approach is similar to the following in C# (which uses a while(true) loop instead of recursion):

[Finding Fibonacci sequence in C#. [Project Euler Exercise]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580985/finding-fibonacci-sequence-in-c-project-euler-exercise/1581055#1581055)

Comment: C# use of yield is something I'm going to have to work on.  A completely new way of thinking about yield.  I'm just learning F#, so f# answer is cool, but makes my head hurt trying to understand it.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Indeed!  I picked up the Expert F# book in 2008, read through it and absorbed as much as I could, but wasn't really ready for it at that time.  However, it got me experimenting with yield/IEnumerable and delegates in C# at my day job (even pre-linq C# 2.0 has those features), and I've found now, two years later, I'm having a much easier time tacking F# in earnest.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, mutable variables and while loops are usually a good sign that your code is not very functional. Also the fibonacci series, doesn't start with 1,2 - it starts with 0,1 or 1,1 depending on who you ask.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
let rec fabListHelper (a:int,b:int,n:int) =
  if a+b < n then
    a+b :: fabListHelper (b, a+b, n)
  else
    [];;

let fabList (n:int) = 0 :: 1 :: fabListHelper (0,1, n);;

(*> fabList 400;;
val it : int list = [0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34; 55; 89; 144; 233; 377]*)
```

Comment: fabListHelper wouldn't be tail-call optimized would it?  I mean the cons "a+b::fabListHelp(b,a+b,n)" prevents tail call optimization doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

One using aggregation (fold):

```
let fib n = 
  [1..n] |> List.fold (fun ac _ -> (ac |> List.take 2 |> List.sum) :: ac) [1;1] |> List.rev
```

Answer (score 1):

One with an array:

```
let fibonacci n = [|1..n|] |> Array.fold (fun (a,b) _ -> b, a + b) (0,1) |> fst
```

Answer (score 1):

This function "fib" will return a list of Fibonacci numbers that are not greater than 500

```
let rec fib a b =
    let current = a + b
    match current with
    | _ when current >= 500 -> []
    | _ -> current :: fib b current 

let testFib = fib 1 2;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article by .Net guru Scott Hanselman on generating fibonacci series in F#

```
let rec fib n = if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode13FibonacciEdition.aspx

It also compares with other languages as a reference

Comment: a) This is a terribly inefficient way to calculate a fibonacci number and b) using this to create a list is even less efficient because you have to calculate the whole thing again for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

One more codata'ish way:

```
let rec fib = seq {
  yield! seq {0..1}
  yield! Seq.map (fun(a,b)->a+b) <| Seq.zip fib (Seq.skip 1 fib)
}
let a = fib |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score -1):

The great solution of Scott Hanselman does not report the 0 the fibonacci sequence starts with.

So here is a minor change to his solution to also report the 0.
I used a small list from 0 to 10 to display the first 11 items of the sequence.

```
let nums=[0..10]
let rec fib n = if n < 1 then 0 else if n < 2 then 1 else fib (n-2) + fib(n-1)
let finres = List.map fib nums
printfn "%A" finres
```

I'm new and incompetent in relation to f# and still not totally fully understanding the need of it. But found this an interesting test.

Just for fun : If found a formula of Binet that calculates the n-th Fibonacci number.
Unfortunately some floating point functions are needed to get the integer result back in the end :
[Fibonacci formula of Binet][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMkxf.png

```
let fib2 n = (1.0 / sqrt(5.0)) * ( (((1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) /2.0)**n)  -  (((1.0 -  sqrt(5.0)) /2.0)**n) )
let fib2res = fib2 10.0
System.Console.WriteLine(fib2res)
let strLine = System.Console.ReadLine()
```

A quick and dirty translation to f# would be as shown above. I'm sure others can improve on this in matter of style and efficiency. The example calculates the 10th number. The result will be 55.

Comment: Your answer seems to be a duplicate of @DavidReihans'. Also, as noted in comments to other questions, this approach is neither effective nor tail-recursive.