# F# generator function equivalent

Tags: javascript, f#

In JavaScript, ES6 flavor, was introduced generator function so this kind of constructs are possible:

```
var fib = function *(max) {
  var x = 0, y = 1, tmp = 1;
  while (tmp<max) {
    yield tmp;
    x = y; 
    y = tmp;
    tmp = x + y;
  }
}
var fibgen = fib(3000);
```

Here `fibgen` is a generator that will produce lower than 3000 Fibonacci numbers.

What would be an equivalent construct in F#?

LE: I'm not looking for an [algorithm for Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845744/generating-fibonacci-series-in-f). But for some generator function that would lazily emit a value when iterating over it.

Comment: where is your attempted solution?

Comment: I am a very beginner in functional programming. All I can think a about is the imperative implementation. And this is not what i want.

Comment: You should clarify (by editing the question) what you are looking for. The equivalent construct in F# is virtually identical using a sequence expression and mutable variables. Do you want to know the idiomatic F# approach? Or the idiomatic functional approach?

Comment: I agree it was not clear enough. I'm not looking for an algorithm for Fibonacci series. But for some generator function that would emit a value when iterating over it. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: F# has a "yield" keyword too. Google that and you should get some ideas.

Comment: I know you are new to SO however it is expected that when asking a question that what you have attempted or found in shown so that we can see that you are not being lazy and making us do all of the work. Thus you are getting down votes on your question.

Comment: I thought that laziness is a virtue. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this MSDN article for lazily evaluated sequences in F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx). A possible solution to the given problem, using `Seq.unfold`:

```
let fibTo limit =
    Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) -> Some (b, (b, a+b))) (0I, 1I)
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun i -> i <= limit)
```

The first line creates the Fibonacci sequence, lazily evaluated. The second limits it. `I` is the literal for arbitrary-length integers. Test:

```
fibTo 3000I |> Seq.iter (printf "%A ")
```

Output: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584`

```
fibTo (pown 10I 30)
```

Returns the Fibonnaci sequence up to 898923707008479989274290850145 – the last value no larger than 10^30 – if evaluated that far.