# How does this c++ function work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int myFunction(int n)
{
    int x;
    if (n==1 || n==2)
       x = 1;
    else
        x = myFunction(n-2) + myFunction(n-1);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n,a;
    n = 7;
    a = myFunction(n);
    cout << "x is: " << a; 

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output to this is "x is: 13".
How do I get x = 13 when I do n = 7?
It seems that the function repeats some number of times until x=1.

Comment: A debugger, some inline print statements or just a plain trace on paper of the function run can tell you

Comment: recursion (n): see recursion

Comment: @FredLarson, where's the terminating condition? :) :)

Comment: @RSahu: I guess you can terminate once you figure it out. 8v)

Comment: Maybe it would help to see the problem in F#:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845744/generating-fibonacci-series-in-f

Answer (score 1):

I will walk you through it for a simpler example where the function is 4, but the overall concept is the same for 7 as well.

First call: `myFunction(4)` and inside the function `n = 4`.

Since `n` does not equal 1 or 2, we skip to the else:

```
x = myFunction(3) + myFunction(2);
x = myFunction(1) + myFunction(2) + 1; // If there is a 1, that means 
                                       // that we went to the if 
                                       // clause, not the else, since
                                       // n was either 1 or 2
x = 1 + 1 + 1;
x = 3;
```

This concept is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and can be very useful at times. Your function currently calculates the nth fibonacci number.

On a side note, you should read why using `system("PAUSE");` is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107717/6525260).