# Help with LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, fibonacci

How to write a LINQ Expression (method call syntax preferred) that gives a list of fibonacci numbers lying within a certain range, say 1 to 1000 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK; for a more "FP" answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<long, long, long, IEnumerable<long>> fib = null;
        fib = (n, m, cap) => n + m > cap ? Enumerable.Empty<long>()
            : Enumerable.Repeat(n + m, 1).Concat(fib(m, n + m, cap));

        var list = fib(0, 1, 1000).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that **in theory** this can be written as a single lambda, but that is [very hard](http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx).

Comment: damn, that some impressive LINQ. +1

Comment: Impressive LINQ? This looks more like Functional Programming 101 to me. Still, to most imperative C# programmers it's bound to look mighty impressive.

Comment: Be glad that C# programmers get introduced to functional programming with LINQ, even if some don't realize it yet. When their minds are ready, functional programmers can take over the world! [insert evil cackle here]

Comment: Marc, I've found this clearer explanation of recursive lambdas, that actually addresses the Fibonacci numbers and that's IMO much clearer than the link you gave: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Using the iterator-block answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406446/refactoring-fibonacci-algorithm):

```
    foreach (long i in Fibonacci()
           .SkipWhile(i => i < 1)
           .TakeWhile(i => i <= 1000)) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

or for a list:

```
var list = Fibonacci().SkipWhile(i => i < 1).TakeWhile(i => i <= 1000)
                 .ToList();
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
```

Comment: I want a solution that doesn't use any loops. Only LINQ methods allowed.

Comment: And what do you think most of LINQ(-to-objects) is, under the hood? More seriously; what exactly do you have in mind? If you mean at the caller, just add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`. If you mean in the implementation, well - it is an infinite sequence... you may have to loop at some point...

Comment: I am playing with functional programming and thus want no explicit loops. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is enumerator base solution. Its a lazy evaluation. So next number is generated when MoveNext() is done.

```
   foreach (int k in Fibonacci.Create(10))
       Console.WriteLine(k);


    class Fibonacci : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        private FibonacciEnumertor fibEnum;
        public Fibonacci(int max) {
            fibEnum = new FibonacciEnumertor(max);
        }
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() {
            return fibEnum;
        }


        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
        public static IEnumerable<int> Create(int max) {
            return new Fibonacci(max);
        }

        private class FibonacciEnumertor : IEnumerator<int>
        {
            private int a, b, c, max;
            public FibonacciEnumertor(int max) {
                this.max = max;
                Reset();
            }
            // 1 1 2 3 5 8
            public int Current {
                get {

                    return c;
                }
            }
            public void Dispose() {

            }

            object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current {
                get { return this.Current; }
            }

            public bool MoveNext() {

                c = a + b;
                if (c == 0)
                    c = 1;
                a = b;
                b = c;
                ;
                return max-- > 0;
            }

            public void Reset() {
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The funny thing is that by the time the compiler has finished mangling it, this isn't very different to the iterator-block approach - just harder to write ;-p

Comment: Yup you right it will be similar to the iterative one.
Actually what i wanted is to give same behavior as following.
                Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
So code might be large but it is reusable and there is no performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

not very performant:

```
val fibonacci = Enumerable
                  .Range(0, 1000)
                  .Aggregate(new List<int>{1,0}, (b,j)=>{
                                b.Insert(0,b[0]+b[1]);
                                return b; });
```

Answer (score 1):

late, but a fast version with the "yield" keyword :-)

```
IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci(int limit)
{
 int number = 1, old = 0;
 while (number < limit)
 {
  yield return number;
  int tmp = number; number += old; old = tmp;
 }
}

var list = Fibonacci(1000).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to print fibonacci using linq

```
        List<int> lst = new List<int> { 0, 1 };

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            int num = lst.Skip(i).Sum();
            lst.Add(num);

            foreach (int number in lst)
                Console.Write(number + " ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```